# postgres user with /bin/nologin

Tags: postgresql

I have an application which creates a postgres database and the user who owns the postgres database has /bin/nologin as their shell.

The database functions without error and is also otherwise secure. Due to best practices it makes sense to not assign a Linux shell to the postgres db owner, postgres runs as this user.

I however have to take a pg_dump of this database for archiving purposes, how can I do that without assigning a valid shell to the username the database runs as?

Comment: `pg_dump -U some_db_user ...` from anywhere you can connect to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo -u pe-postgres /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/postgresql/bin/pg_dumpall -c -f <BACKUP_FILE>.sql
```

does the trick

Answer (score 1):

This is no problem at all.

`pg_dump` is a client tool, and you can use it as a different user on the same machine or from a different machine.

Use the `-h <host/socket> -p <port>` options of `pg_dump` to connect to a database server that might be on a different machine and use `-U <user>` to specify which database user to connect as.

Comment: getting this message

Comment: [root@test56 ~]# /opt/puppetlabs/server/bin/pg_dump  -U pe-puppetdb  -d pe-puppetdb > /var/tmp/db.$(date +%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S).dump
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "pe-puppetdb" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "pe-puppetdb"

Comment: Unless configured with a `map`, [peer authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER) will only work if you are OS user `pe-puppetdb`. You'll have to configure [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) to allow your connection attempt.